# Aurelia - custom editor for kendo grid

Tags: kendo-grid, aurelia

I have to use the custom editor for aurelia-kendo grid. I have found the following example in internet: (this is part of html-file)

```
<div ref="divConditions">
    <ak-grid k-data-source.bind="datasource" k-widget.bind="grid" ref="gridConditions"
        k-editable="mode: 'popup', template: kendo.template($(this.popup_editor).html())">
                <ak-col k-title="Short code" k-field="shortCode"></ak-col>
                <ak-col k-title="Title" k-field="title"></ak-col>
                <ak-col k-title="Created" k-field="created"></ak-col>            
                <ak-col k-command.bind="['edit']" k-title="&nbsp;" width="75px"></ak-col>
     </ak-grid>
</div>

<script ref="popup_editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    Content
</script>
```

But it didn't work - nothing for Edit button click.

I also have tried the following code: (this is part of ts-file)

```
attached() {

    ....
    var grid = this.gridConditions;
    var template = this.popup_editor;

    $(grid).kendoGrid({
        editable: {
            mode: "popup",
            template: kendo.template($(template).html())
        }
    });
}
```

The same - no reaction.
I can see any examples for Kendo UI, but not for Aurelia-Kendo.... unfortunately.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try `k-editable.bind="{mode: 'popup', template: kendo.template($(this.popup_editor).html())}"`. Also make sure to have all necessary "require" tags on top of your template. This should at least point you to the right direction.